# Estimate Python to Python IPC latency

Tags: python, synchronization, multiprocessing, ipc

For a Python application I need to simultaneously handle an OpenGL display output and serial outputs (e.g. to an Arduino). However, I would ideally like to run the different kinds of outputs in separate processes.

Since the display and serial output need to be precisely synchronized I'm trying to figure out just how fast the inter-process communication within Python is (e.g. using `multiprocessing.Pipe`). But I've run into an issue trying to benchmark this for a given hardware configuration.

If I use `time.time()` to estimate the IPC latency it appears to be less than 1us, which - to me - seems to be too fast.
When I tried using `time.perf_counter()` on the other hand, I consistently got negative latencies, which is even weirder.

Here is the sample code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pipe, Process, Event
import time

direct = False

timing_fun = time.time
#timing_fun = time.perf_counter

def p1(p1out, p2in, start):

    start.wait()
    print('Run p1 at %s' % str(timing_fun()))
    while True:
        print('Sending...')
        if not(direct):
            p1out.send(timing_fun())
        else:
            p2in.send(timing_fun())

        time.sleep(2.)

def p2(p2out, start):

    start.set()
    print('Run p2 at %s' % str(timing_fun()))
    while True:
        if p2out.poll():
            print('%.7f' % (timing_fun() - p2out.recv()))


def master():

    print('Start master')
    print('Running in %s mode' % ('direct' if direct else 'referred'))
    p1in, p1out = Pipe()
    p2in, p2out = Pipe()
    start = Event()

    process1 = Process(target=p1, args=(p1out, p2in, start))
    process1.start()

    process2 = Process(target=p2, args=(p2out, start))
    process2.start()


    print('Run main loop')
    while True:
        if p1in.poll():
            p2in.send(p1in.recv())


if __name__ == '__main__':

    master()
```

Running with `time.time()`:

```
Start master
Running in referred mode
Run main loop
Run p2 at 1569056480.1104207
Run p1 at 1569056480.1104207
Sending...
0.0000000
Sending...
0.0000000
Sending...
0.0000000
```

Running with `time.perf_counter()`:

```
Start master
Running in referred mode
Run main loop
Run p2 at 0.0628994
Run p1 at 0.0821299
Sending...
-0.0187006
Sending...
-0.0187737
Sending...
-0.0190505
Sending...
-0.0191084
```

Does anyone know a sensible way to benchmark the latency or has any experience as to what kind of latency I could realistically expect?

Answer (score 0):

After some more tinkering I found that, what seems to work is simply bouncing the message back to the process which initially sent it and using `time.perf_counter()` to calculate the difference:

```
from multiprocessing import Pipe, Process, Event
import time

timing_fun = time.perf_counter

def p1(p1out, p2in, start):

    start.wait()
    print('Run p1 at %s' % str(timing_fun()))
    while True:
        if p1out.poll(timeout=0.1):
            print('%.7f' % (timing_fun() - p1out.recv()))

        time.sleep(2.)

        print('Sending...')
        p2in.send(timing_fun())


def p2(p2out, p1in, start):

    start.set()
    print('Run p2 at %s' % str(timing_fun()))
    while True:
        if p2out.poll():
            msg = p2out.recv()
            p1in.send(msg)


def master():

    print('Start master')
    p1in, p1out = Pipe()
    p2in, p2out = Pipe()
    start = Event()

    process1 = Process(target=p1, args=(p1out, p2in, start))
    process1.start()

    process2 = Process(target=p2, args=(p2out, p1in, start))
    process2.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    master()
```

According to the documentation for `time.perf_counter()` the reference point should be system-wide, so I still don't know why my initial approach did not work when I called it from two separate processes (maybe someone has the answer to that?). But at least the above solution appears to work, because it puts the 2-way communication latency of Pipes just below 1ms, which seems reasonable (i9-9820X@3.3GHz base speed):

```
Start master
Run p2 at 0.0653889
Run p1 at 0.0928306
Sending...
0.0004457
Sending...
0.0003819
Sending...
0.0006137
Sending...
0.0005876
Sending...
0.0005943
```